# Using Variable as expression in Derived column transformation SSIS

Tags: variables, ssis, expression, transformation, dataflow

Essentially I a SSIS pkg with an Execute SQL statement that dynamically writes a REPLACE function based on some table values. (ie REPLACE(REPLACE(Col1,"***","",),"@@@","")

ExecuteSQL result is put to variable @Cleanse

In my Derived Column conversion Im trying to call @User::Cleanse as an expression in to replace the Value of the Col1  from the DataFlow.

The result appears to be pulling the result of @Cleanse and using it as a string value rather than applying it as the REPLACE function.

When Debugging the @Cleanse value appear to be putting \ in the string, which I dont think should matter as it seems to be appliying this to other values without a problem

The result is that when running out to the CSV this is putting

"REPLACE(REPLACE(Col1" in Col1

"***" in Col2

) in Col3 etc etc

How can I get the Derived column transformation to 'see' the variable as the function, not a string value?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `EvaluateAsExpression` property of the variable to `True`.

However, binding variables as parameters to an SQL query using the `Variable Mappings` pane of the Execute SQL task might be a better solution

Comment: Are you trying to pass the actual expression to your derived column transformation? That is, as far as i know, impossible.

Comment: Hi @Jeroen

Ok? Perhaps Im missing something

If I set the var to be Evaluate as Expression I need to write the expression using the editor....so For these purposes I created @ Cleanse2 with the Expression of User::Cleanse

This appears to be geving me the same result...i.e. pulling the string through as a string not using it as the REPLACE Statement.

Comment: Ahhhhh

Yes I am

The actual expression is compiled and witten by the ExecuteSQL task. So the reult being put to the variable = REPLACE(REPLACE(Col1,"*",""),"@@@"<"")

I am then calling the variable in the Expression of the derived column transformation

Comment: Thanks Jerome

I have since tacked the SQL as a variable paramter in a later bit of code and seems to be working