# SSIS: Variable as "NEW" derived column

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, control-flow, dataflow

I am trying to write the SQL task results in a flat file. I have a SQL task, followed by foreach loop that parses the object results to variables. Inside the foreach I have a data flow.

Inside the dataflow I have a Derived Column transformation editor, where I am trying to use the variables as columns. This is because I want to write the column in a flat file. However the Derived column keeps complaining about not having any INPUT columns (and writing 0 rows to flatfile) and I do not know why.

These are the instructions I am trying to follow: [Using Variable as expression in Derived column transformation SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433369/using-variable-as-expression-in-derived-column-transformation-ssis)

Comment: Is there anything prior to this derived column? It looks like the "Columns" is empty which explains your error. If you need a dummy input then use a one line text file as input. This would then get around this problem

Comment: You are right, I needed a dummy column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Derived Column* transformation is a part of Data Flow. Data Flow means that you have a set of rows with columns originated from some Data Flow Source, undergoing DFT transformations like *Derived Column* and then passing rows to Data Flow Destination. Data Flow Transformation needs to have input and output.
In your case - create a *OLE DB Source* with some dummy query like `select 0 as dummy' and direct this data flow to your *Derived Column*. Later you can drop this dummy column.